# Return checkboxes array to php via jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Im trying to send an array of checkboxes (value) to PHP via jquery. How can that be done?

See the following example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="0"> Small
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="1"> Medium
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="2"> Large
<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="3"> X-Large

<input id="ButtonAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
```

jQuery code, couldn't get to work:

```
$("#ButtonAdd").click(function() { 
    var options = $("input:checkbox[name='option[]']");
     $.post("ajax_extras.php", { options:options  },
       function(data)  {
         console.log(data)
    });
});
```

ajax_extras.php file:

```
<?php
 print_r($_POST['options']);
?>
```

Comment: you may need to escape the brackets inside the brackets: `var options = $("input:checkbox[name='option\\[\\]']");`

Comment: @mblase75 i think single slash will escape it ?

Comment: nope you are right  `\\\`  are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape the `[]`

```
var options = $("input:checkbox[name='option\\[\\]']");
```

Comment: Thanks, that work but my browser freeze when it attempting to do ajax or something...  I have tried to remove ajax code and it work.. any clue?

Comment: by `freeze` you mean freeze and then unfreeze or just freezes and then craches? may be you are handling a lot of data?

Comment: The data is only `print_r($_POST['options']);` and only few tickboxes

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` attribute to the checkboxes and do instead:

```
$("#ButtonAdd").click(function() { 
    var options = $("input[type=checkbox].checks");
     $.post("ajax_extras_add_extras.php", { options:options  },
       function(data)  {
         console.log(data)
    });
});
```

Comment: I dont think `input[type=checkbox].checkk` would work because I have couple of tickboxes that is not belong with `option[]` name. I only want to send data to php that has `option[]` name

Comment: Then you place the class wherever you see fit, that's up to you.